# Creating a browser game

Tags: sockets, browser

My goal is to create a game in a browser (a game like wordfeud) and my question is what is the best way for the networking part? In Java, C# and so on you can use socket programming (server-client programming), but how is the best way to do it in a browser?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, node.js is excellent for game server, for the following advantages.

1. Network IO and scalability. Perfect match for game servers, which requires realtime, scalability, high density network IO.
2. The node.js thread model. Single thread is quite suitable for game server, it helps us to handle all the troubles about concurrency, lock and other annoying questions. Multi-process, single thread is ideal for game server.
3. The language advantages. Javascript is powerful, popular and performance good. Further more, if you choose HTML 5 for client, you can reuse a lot of code logic between server and client.

But the original socket.io is single process, if you want scalability and extensibility, some framework may needed. Pomelo is a good candidate for it, it's an open source game server framework in node.js.

Answer (score 1):

**Server side:** `Node.js + socket.io seems appropriate for those types of connections`
**Client side:** `javascript or actionscript from the client side.`

**Example**
PopCap (which makes a bunch of popular facebook games like zuma blitz and bejeweled blitz) uses predominantly flash / actionscript / possibly flex for their games and it seems to do the trick. Javascript would be more accessible to those who wanna play via a phone or tablet though.

Comment: Those are great for server side, but I think he's asking about a way to make outgoing connections from the browser.

Comment: What do you think of of a database instead of socketprogramming?